# C# Input String not in correct format

Tags: c#, string

I can't figure out why the code is in the wrong format. I'm getting the the error on the line of `TotalTicketprice = decimal.Parse(overallTicketCostlabel.Text);` and everything that's associated with it. Anyone know a solution for this?

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Tickets; //Quantity of Tickets
    decimal Price; //price per ticket
    decimal DiscountPercent = 0.1m; // Discount given
    decimal TotalTicketprice; //Ticket price before discount given
    decimal Discount;

    Tickets = int.Parse(ticketQuantityTextBox.Text);
    Price = decimal.Parse(priceTicketTextBox.Text);
    TotalTicketprice = decimal.Parse(overallTicketCostlabel.Text);
    Discount = decimal.Parse(initialDiscountLabel.Text);

    //Ticket Price
    overallTicketCostlabel.Text = (Price * Tickets).ToString("c");

    //Displays Discount
    initialDiscountLabel.Text = (TotalTicketprice * DiscountPercent).ToString("c");

    //Displays Discounted Total Cost
    discountedCostLabel.Text = (TotalTicketprice - Discount).ToString("c");
```

Comment: What is the value of `overallTicketCostlabel.Text` exactly?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint and looking at the value of the variables before you try to parse them into a decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, going from your naming convention, should this be;

```
TotalTicketprice = decimal.Parse(overallTicketCostTextBox.Text);
```

instead of:

```
TotalTicketprice = decimal.Parse(overallTicketCostlabel.Text);
```

You may also want to include some validation to ensure that these are numeric prior to parsing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 overallTicketCostlabel.Text = (Price * Tickets).ToString("c");
```

this formats as a Currency. This means that it will probably have a currency symbol in the text. Like `$ 100` for example.